# Sorting a Mongo query without a field to sort on

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongo collection which includes an array of search terms, e.g.:

```
[ "germany", "austria", "peter" ]
```

Using the technique described at the bottom of this [excellent article](https://www.blogger.com/comment.g?blogID=7935741825228283743&postID=3240900722312619441&page=1&token=1416954311511) by John Page I have implemented a Mongo aggregation which takes a list of search terms (e.g. "germany peter bob") and returns a result set which includes the number of terms which matched each document (not all terms have to match). In this example case:

```
{ "_id": "<id>", "c": 2 }
```

I have sorted the result of this aggregation by the number of matching terms, such that the most relevant ids are first. I end up with an array like this:

```
[ '<id1>', '<id2>', .. ]
```

Now that I have a list of matching ids ordered by relevance, I need to query the database for these documents:

```
doc.find({ "_id": { $in: [ '<id1>', '<id2>', .. ] } })
```

But, of course, that won't return the collection in the same sorted order, and there's nothing in the documents themselves that I can sort on.

Clearly my approach has been wrong, but I can't think of a solution. How can I return a cursor with the results sorted by the relevance that I've calculated?

Note that I can't update the documents with a relevance since multiple users will need to be searching simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

So from the link I guess you did something like

```
aggregate([{$unwind : "$c"},
           {$match: {c :{$in : ["searchterms"]},
           {$group : {"c" : {"$sum" : 1},  _id : "$_id"}}])
```

where `c` are your search terms.

The next step would be to sort according to c by using

```
{$sort: {c:-1}}
```

in your aggreation pipeline.

Now all you need to do is to retrieve the whole documentes instead of just the `_id`. That can be done by modifying the aggregate in the following way:

```
aggregate([{$project: {_id:1,c:1,doc:"$$ROOT"}},
           {$unwind : "$c"},
           {$match: {c :{$in : ["searchterms"]},
           {$group : {"c" : {"$sum" : 1},  _id : "$_id",doc:{$addToSet:"$doc"}}},
           {$sort:{c:-1}}])
```

The project creates documents containing the _id, the searchterm array and a field doc containing the original document which is keept in the `$group` stage.

This should produce results of the form

```
{_id : <id> , c: <# of matching therms>, doc: [<the original document>]}
```

If you want only a limited number of documents you can use `$skip` and `$limit`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I get this error when I add $$ROOT to the $project: "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'".  I can't find any mention of $$ROOT in the Mongo docs either...

Comment: The doc is [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) an example in [this section](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pivot-data). Tried it exacatly as posted.

Comment: Ah, it seem that variables are not available in version 2.4 which is what I currently have to use :( Is there another way?

Comment: Depending on how much fields from your documents you need to retrieve you could try to add (the relevant) fields manually to the doc field in the $project operation

Comment: There's not really a great solution for 2.4, but your solution is excellent for 2.6 so I'm marking this as correct.